# Compress Base64 String

Tags: swift, compression

```
let audioData = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: aacPath))
let audioContent = audioData?.base64EncodedString()
```

I get the audioContent with base64 String. But the string is too big. What I want to do is make the audioContent smaller, that is compress my base64 String.

Are there any ways to do that? Please help me!!

Comment: Why don't you compress the original `audioData` instead? That is smaller to begin with.

Comment: AAC is already compressed, so it's impossible to compress the resulting base64 string because it doesn't contain redundant data. You'd need to re-encode the `audioData` with lower bitrate or use different audio encoding

Comment: Another option is to send the raw bytes as application/octet-stream. This will reduce the data size about 25%.

Comment: I have tried compress audioData, when I record about 1 minute, the audioData is about 760,000 to 740,000

Answer (score 0):

Since your audio data is compressed, the best a compressor can do is undo the expansion introduced by the Base-64 encoding, by going back to using all 256 byte values in the result. In that case, the best compression would be to simply not Base-64 encode in the first place. Find a way to send binary data.

The only other alternative would be to decompress the audio data and recompress it with a more effective and/or more aggressive lossy audio compressor, possibly accepting some loss of quality.